# comparing length of strings C

Tags: c, string

I'm having trouble with comparing strings in C. Firstly, I need to find the length of each string from command-line arguments, and then compare them as well as printing the biggest one.

So far, it's just printing the length of each typed string. I need to compare them according to length, not alphabetic order.

I don't understand why is it now working and what I should do fix it? Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, length;

    for(i = 0; i<argc; i++)
    {
        length = strlen(argv[i]);
        printf("%s %d\n", argv[i], length);

        if(strlen(argv[i]) < strlen(argv[i+1]))
        {
            printf("%s is the biggest \n", argv[i+1]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s is the biggest \n", argv[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all you need to fix the off-by-one overflow. When accessing `argv[i+1]` you may only iterate while `i < argc - 1`

Comment: your code segfaults. have you read coredump to find out where its faulting?

Comment: and argv[0] is the program name, not an argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int i, max_length, max_index;

   max_index = 0;
   max_length = strlen(argv[0]);

   for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
   {
        if(strlen(argv[i]) > max_length)
        {   
            max_length = strlen(argv[i]);
            max_index = i;
        }
    }

   printf("The longest is: %s with length equal: %d\n", argv[max_index], max_length);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome :) Please note that I compared also the application name (`argv[0]`). I wasn't certain whether it should also be checked.

Comment: Yeap, exactly,i see that. It wasnt actually, it was just my misunderstanding with argv[0]

Answer (score 8):

There are a few problems with your code.

First of all, `argv[i+1]` is an illegal operation if you're doing `i < argc` in the `for`. You need to change `i < argc` to `i < argc - 1` in the `for`.

Secondly, you are probably not comparing the strings you want. `argv[0]` is the string representing the path of your program; the first argument passed to your program is `argv[1]`. Therefore, you need to change the  `i = 0` in the `for` to `i = 1`.

Finally, if you **only** want the biggest string, you should not do any printing in the `for` loop. Rather, you should create two variables like `max_length` and `max_length_idx` where you would store the length and index of the largest string found so far. Then, after the `for` loop, your program would print out the string `argv[max_length_idx]`.

Comment: For an upvote, don't forget to tell the OP that if only the longest string is desired, then there should be no printing within the for loop....

Comment: @Ray Toal: I thought this was obvious... :)

Comment: @RayToal: yea I thought so too. Added an explanation though :)

Comment: Okay +1 but you never know.... :) Just thought it would make for a more complete and helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will not segfault ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, length;

    for(i = 0; i<argc - 1; i++)
    {
       length = strlen(argv[i]);
       printf("%s %d\n", argv[i], length);

    if(strlen(argv[i]) < strlen(argv[i+1]))
    {
       printf("%s is the biggest \n", argv[i+1]);
    }
    else
    {
       printf("%s is the biggest \n", argv[i]);
    }
   }
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Yeap, thank you, I tried it, it make sense know why I had run-time error